# Create multidimentional array from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays :

```
groups = array (
  array (1 => string 'INFORMATIQUE ET MULTIMEDIA'),
  array (2 => string 'VEHICULES' ),
  array (3 => string 'IMMOBILIER' ),
  array (4 => string 'POUR LA MAISON ET JARDIN'),
  array (5 => string 'HABILLEMENT ET BIEN ETRE'),
  array (6 => string 'LOISIRS ET DIVERTISSEMENT'),
  array (7 => string 'EMPLOI ET SERVICE' ),
  array (8 => string 'ENTREPRISE' ),
  array (9 => string 'AUTRES' ));
```

This is an array of categories groups
I have in the other side an array of categories :

```
$categories = array (
    array (
      'id' => string '1' ,
      'name' => string 'Téléphones' ,
      'groupid' => string '1' 
    ),
    array (
      'id' => string '2',
      'name' => string 'Tablette' ,
      'groupid' => string '1'
    ),
    array (
      'id' => string '3' ,
      'name' => string 'Voitures' ,
      'groupid' => string '2'
   ), 
    array (
      'id' => string '4' ,
      'name' => string 'Motos',
      'groupid' => string '2' 
    )
);
```

What i want is :

```
$result = array (
  'INFORMATIQUE ET MULTIMEDIA' => 
    array (
      1 => string 'Téléphones',
      2 => string 'Tablette'
    )
  'VEHICULES' => 
    array (
      4 => string 'Motos',
      4 => string 'Motos'
    )
);
```

This is my code but it doesn't work but the problem is that it records a single line :

```
    foreach($groups as $id => $name)
    {
        $n = 1;
        foreach($categories as $k=>$v)
        {
            if($v['groupid'] == $id){
                $result[$name] = array_fill($v['id'], 1, $v['name']);
                $n ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check once my answer with the output link.thanks

Comment: In your output array  keys are same in the  `'VEHICULES'` which is not correct. it should be 3,4 instead of 4,4

Comment: Is that code give you exact output what you shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, it will work for you

```
<?php
$result = null;
foreach($goups as $key => $value)
    foreach($categories as $categorie)
        if(  $key == $categorie['groupid'] )
            $result[$value][] = $categorie['name']

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got most of the code right, but you keep assigning all your data in the first index of your sub-array, which is why you get one single result. Try the code below

```
foreach($groups as $id => $name)
{
    $n = 1;
    foreach($categories as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($v['groupid'] == $id){
            $result[$name][$n] = $['name'];
            $n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($groups as $id => $name)
{
    foreach($categories as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($v['groupid'] == $id){
            $result[$name][] = array($v['id'] => $v['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

or a  simple one.

```
    foreach($categories as $k=>$v)
    {
        $result[$groups[$v['groupid']]][] = array($v['id'] => $v['name']);
    }
```